# MySql version 5.7.12 getting crashed

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, segmentation-fault

We have migrated from SqlServer 2008 to MySql version 5.7.12 on AWS EC2 instance of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Version. The server is getting crashed repeatedly. The logs are as below:

```
2016-05-25T06:17:40.045804Z 2946 [Note] Aborted connection 2946 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.4.138' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:17:40.046804Z 2938 [Note] Aborted connection 2938 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.4.138' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:17:40.046817Z 2945 [Note] Aborted connection 2945 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.4.138' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:22:41.447479Z 2985 [Note] Aborted connection 2985 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.48' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:22:41.447483Z 2964 [Note] Aborted connection 2964 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.48' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:24:11.317802Z 2931 [Note] Aborted connection 2931 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:34:51.345602Z 3008 [Note] Aborted connection 3008 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.48' (Got an error reading communication packets)
06:35:45 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=52428800
read_buffer_size=20971520
max_used_connections=284
max_threads=214
thread_count=283
connection_count=283
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 8843311 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fe34c6be4d0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fe40a536e40 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0xebef8c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x451)[0x7acb61]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fe6f98f4340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Item_func_case7cleanupEv+0x21)[0x8236b1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13cleanup_itemsP4Item+0x21)[0xc94431]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN5TABLE16cleanup_gc_itemsEv+0x34)[0xd37234]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z19close_thread_tablesP3THD+0x5f)[0xc404ff]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x4b7)[0xc970c7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x50)[0xc20d00]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjb+0x384)[0xc228e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr29validate_lex_and_execute_coreEP3THDPjb+0xab)[0xc2327b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt7executeEP3THDPj+0x120)[0xc24410]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x4f4)[0xc1c624]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head15execute_triggerEP3THDRK25st_mysql_const_lex_stringS4_P10GRANT_INFO+0x1fc)[0xc1cedc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7Trigger7executeEP3THD+0x10d)[0xd403ed]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13Trigger_chain16execute_triggersEP3THD+0x18)[0xd434a8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN24Table_trigger_dispatcher16process_triggersEP3THD23enum_trigger_event_type29enum_trigger_action_time_typeb+0x52)[0xd3cee2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_updateP3THDR4ListI4ItemES4_y15enum_duplicatesPyS6_+0x134d)[0xd1cead]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_update23try_single_table_updateEP3THDPb+0x1b6)[0xd1f346]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_update7executeEP3THD+0x27)[0xd1f667]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x5d0)[0xc971e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x50)[0xc20d00]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjb+0x384)[0xc228e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr29validate_lex_and_execute_coreEP3THDPjb+0xab)[0xc2327b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt7executeEP3THDPj+0x120)[0xc24410]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x4f4)[0xc1c624]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head15execute_triggerEP3THDRK25st_mysql_const_lex_stringS4_P10GRANT_INFO+0x1fc)[0xc1cedc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7Trigger7executeEP3THD+0x10d)[0xd403ed]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13Trigger_chain16execute_triggersEP3THD+0x18)[0xd434a8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN24Table_trigger_dispatcher16process_triggersEP3THD23enum_trigger_event_type29enum_trigger_action_time_typeb+0x52)[0xd3cee2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_updateP3THDR4ListI4ItemES4_y15enum_duplicatesPyS6_+0x134d)[0xd1cead]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_update23try_single_table_updateEP3THDPb+0x1b6)[0xd1f346]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_update7executeEP3THD+0x27)[0xd1f667]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x5d0)[0xc971e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x50)[0xc20d00]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjb+0x384)[0xc228e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr29validate_lex_and_execute_coreEP3THDPjb+0xab)[0xc2327b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt7executeEP3THDPj+0x120)[0xc24410]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x4f4)[0xc1c624]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head17execute_procedureEP3THDP4ListI4ItemE+0x757)[0xc200b7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x1c25)[0xc98835]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x385)[0xc9d3e5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0x8d7)[0xc9dd27]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x177)[0xc9f667]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x278)[0xd5a138]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0xee4224]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7fe6f98ec182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fe6f8df947d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fe34dd976e0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 3055
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2016-05-25T06:35:45.130129Z mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
2016-05-25T06:35:45.131247Z mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2016-05-25T06:35:45.136417Z 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 30000)
2016-05-25T06:35:45.136469Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_connections: 214 (requested 700)
2016-05-25T06:35:45.136472Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 400 (requested 4000)
2016-05-25T06:35:45.285890Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.12) starting as process 5208 ...
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291032Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291101Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291118Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291129Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291152Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291417Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-05-25T06:35:45.291538Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-05-25T06:35:45.298282Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 10G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2016-05-25T06:35:45.777778Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-05-25T06:35:45.835555Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2016-05-25T06:35:45.853945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-05-25T06:35:45.893013Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 688601815952
2016-05-25T06:35:46.011211Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688607058432
2016-05-25T06:35:46.130727Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688612301312
2016-05-25T06:35:46.250410Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688617544192
2016-05-25T06:35:46.369991Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688622787072
2016-05-25T06:35:46.439395Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd' with space ID 8686, since the redo log references ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd with space ID 8685.
2016-05-25T06:35:46.621020Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688628029952
2016-05-25T06:35:46.926647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688633272832
2016-05-25T06:35:47.220662Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688638515712
2016-05-25T06:35:47.523115Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688643758592
2016-05-25T06:35:47.813625Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688649001472
2016-05-25T06:35:48.013840Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:48.013907Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:48.109329Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688603126272
2016-05-25T06:35:48.245377Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688608369152
2016-05-25T06:35:48.380703Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688613612032
2016-05-25T06:35:48.516794Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688618854912
2016-05-25T06:35:48.653082Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688624097792
2016-05-25T06:35:48.942457Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688629340672
2016-05-25T06:35:49.258740Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688634583552
2016-05-25T06:35:49.573738Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688639826432
2016-05-25T06:35:49.890260Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688645069312
2016-05-25T06:35:50.194665Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688650312192
2016-05-25T06:35:50.325541Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.325606Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.325619Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.325628Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.325840Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.325891Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.325924Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './dbowithrw/#sql-ib824219-1537447590.ibd' with space ID 8686. Another data file called ./dbowithrw/sureshprasad.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.343396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 688652957751
2016-05-25T06:35:50.344666Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-05-25T06:35:50.344689Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-05-25T06:35:50.635987Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
2016-05-25T06:35:51.610469Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2016-05-25T06:35:51.931405Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2016-05-25T06:35:51.931566Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2016-05-25T06:35:51.931607Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-05-25T06:35:51.980053Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-05-25T06:35:51.980939Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-25T06:35:51.980966Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-25T06:35:51.981311Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-05-25T06:35:52.031470Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.12 started; log sequence number 688652957751
2016-05-25T06:35:52.031491Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6196ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2016-05-25T06:35:52.031700Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-05-25T06:35:52.031853Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-05-25T06:35:52.036324Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2016-05-25T06:35:52.036535Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2016-05-25T06:35:52.037547Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
2016-05-25T06:35:52.037582Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2016-05-25T06:35:52.037634Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2016-05-25T06:35:52.213332Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-05-25T06:35:52.213498Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.12'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2016-05-25T06:35:52.244629Z 2 [Warning] IP address '10.0.0.100' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:35:55.287910Z 7 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.58' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:36:02.660844Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 160525 12:06:02
2016-05-25T06:36:11.007067Z 14 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.48' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:36:20.359394Z 13 [Note] Aborted connection 13 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.58' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:38:22.358943Z 29 [Warning] IP address '172.16.3.72' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:38:51.591178Z 26 [Note] Aborted connection 26 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.58' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T06:39:17.753741Z 34 [Warning] IP address '172.16.3.53' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:41:43.343490Z 39 [Warning] IP address '172.16.2.172' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:42:32.528345Z 43 [Warning] IP address '172.16.5.181' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:43:55.808222Z 49 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.127' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:44:33.582066Z 51 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.93' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:46:10.717352Z 56 [Warning] IP address '10.0.0.254' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:46:25.281681Z 57 [Warning] IP address '172.16.4.138' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:49:08.356412Z 78 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.124' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:49:14.488339Z 79 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.29' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:52:22.121133Z 88 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.87' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T06:59:24.495151Z 81 [Note] Aborted connection 81 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.93' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.481888Z 71 [Note] Aborted connection 71 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.481936Z 70 [Note] Aborted connection 70 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.486902Z 93 [Note] Aborted connection 93 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.488708Z 62 [Note] Aborted connection 62 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.488746Z 60 [Note] Aborted connection 60 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.491444Z 53 [Note] Aborted connection 53 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.491476Z 54 [Note] Aborted connection 54 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.491550Z 72 [Note] Aborted connection 72 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.492401Z 61 [Note] Aborted connection 61 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.493221Z 63 [Note] Aborted connection 63 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.496796Z 65 [Note] Aborted connection 65 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.498087Z 69 [Note] Aborted connection 69 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:01:49.498770Z 2 [Note] Aborted connection 2 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '10.0.0.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:02:03.795662Z 122 [Warning] IP address '172.16.3.245' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T07:03:19.123593Z 110 [Note] Aborted connection 110 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.93' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:04:45.370077Z 138 [Note] Aborted connection 138 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.1.93' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:32.471694Z 145 [Warning] IP address '172.16.1.72' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2016-05-25T07:06:35.076698Z 103 [Note] Aborted connection 103 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:35.076745Z 100 [Note] Aborted connection 100 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:35.076849Z 104 [Note] Aborted connection 104 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:35.076859Z 135 [Note] Aborted connection 135 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:35.076919Z 105 [Note] Aborted connection 105 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:35.077813Z 134 [Note] Aborted connection 134 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:35.078668Z 111 [Note] Aborted connection 111 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-05-25T07:06:35.079450Z 99 [Note] Aborted connection 99 to db: 'dbowithrw' user: 'cwuser' host: '172.16.2.172' (Got an error reading communication packets)
07:08:48 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=52428800
read_buffer_size=20971520
max_used_connections=72
max_threads=214
thread_count=58
connection_count=58
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 8819493 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fe5f4402670
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fe6b1d60e40 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0xebef8c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x451)[0x7acb61]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fe99f0de340]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fe5f590f5c0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 102
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Any pointers or help as to where we are going wrong will be greatly appreciated? Also, a small update, we had upgraded the MySql from 5.7.8 RC version? Can upgradtion also be an issue for error of this type to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by setting of the variables in the my.cnf file. The variables were calculated with the help of [My Sql Calculator](http://www.mysqlcalculator.com) with the help of which I was able to calculate the optimal amount of memory allocated for various purposes. One of the mistake that was done was that sort buffer size was set to 40 mb. That resulted is very less not of connections (< 270) while the DB system required about 1200 connections in total. That was a major relief. We had also given 15GB memory to the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

There was another issue with the slow running queries. In MS SQL, most of our select queries were run `with(nolock)` on tables. We had done that global level change through config by setting the configuration to `read uncommited` (default is `repeatable read`) that had boosted the performance of the queries significatly. (This may not be suitably desired for many others). But, for us it worked well.

Also, in the stored procedures, dropping the temporary tables did a reasonable work. Earlier, we were under wrong impression that as soon as the connection from the application is closed, the temporary table will be dropped which turned out to be false. So, we had manually dropped the temporary table created. (We were using temporary tables to emulate the functionality of rank, dense rank as in sql server). With this, we were able to convert the migration reasonably well.

[image: My Sql Calculation for memory from My Sql Calculator]

Answer (score 0):

Your read_buffer_size of 20971520*max_threads means this one memory requirement is 4G of the 8,819,493 K bytes required.  Tell us how much memory your machine has, please.
Since read_buffer_size serves scanning tables sequentially, a possible reasonable request would be read_buffer_size=1048576.  A scan of 10M data would only require 10 reads.
If you could post show global variables and show global status, we could better assist.

Comment: We had provided 30 GB RAM EC2 Instance for the MySql server running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version.